# Javascript that prevents XSS

Tags: javascript, xss

is there a way that I could automatically format the input box via Javascript that prevents XSS before the user tries to click on the submit button?

like for instance, after a user types a script attack on a textbox, the javascript automatically formats the value within the textbox to a safe format.

btw, i'm not just relying on this procedure to prevent XSS, its just that our client base have phrases that triggers the ASP.Net to consider it as a XSS. here's the exact example:

the phrase: **`OMY G<W TUBE/OVARY`** will trigger the page to consider this as XSS while **`OMY G< W TUBE/OVARY`** isn't considered as a potential risk.

Comment: Could you do *something* in JavaScript? Sure, would it be effective? not at all.  The people who would use this kind of exploit can easily bypass anything you put in JavaScript to prevent it in a console command or two.

Comment: i'm already expecting this, but if a single change in their text can just allow them to enter the right value then i'm Okay with that. I could just disable the pagevalidation and htmlencode all strings entering the system, but i'm afraid to take that risk. i would rather have the injection checking ON and have this to help the users input the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not hard, assuming that you can figure out exactly what triggers the ASP.Net XSS filter. For example, this will fix your shown case:

```
<form id="form" onsubmit="fix()">
    <input id="textbox" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
    function fix() {
        var t = document.getElementById('textbox');
        t.value = t.value.replace(/<(\w)/, '< $1');
    }
</script>
```

**Please understand that this "solution" will NOT prevent XSS attacks in any way whatsoever, or validate the input in any way. XSS attacks can ONLY be prevented server-side.**

Comment: No, it won't. If JavaScript is disabled the invalid data will be sent through; and furthermore, it only "fixes" things sent through this form. It is not the only way to submit data to a server (you can craft the request manually). Data *must* be validated on display, not on input. This is the only way to do it correctly. Everything else is wrong.

Comment: This is not effective, the attacker can just disable JavaScript and avoid the filter. Or it could remove the event handler with a tool like Firebug or Groundspeed. Input validation on the client side does not work, the attacker can remove/bypass/cancel the filter. As @silky mention, has to be on the server-side.

Comment: there is server side prevention.

Comment: NOTE: I allowed this answer not because it's the BEST PRACTICE as @Silky perfectly justified but because its the solution needed without TURNING OFF the Page Validation that protects the asp.net page. Please take note that I also have SERVER SIDE prevention aside from this.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not.

XSS can only be prevented at server time, by formatting the untrusted data for the given context it is about to be displayed in.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. However, Martin is not asking how to prevent XSS. He is merely asking how to thwart ASP.Net's XSS prevention system.

Comment: @Mark: No he's not, and the way to "thwart" ASP.NET's prevention system is to turn it off. It's trivial.

Comment: hello Silky & Mark, I appreciate your comments and you are both correct. I am clearly aware of turning off the prevention system, but I would still like to have it on while allowing them to enter values like my example above. I'm am simply striking a balance between prevention and not restricting people to do what they want. I'm still considering the best practice, but if this solution can just prevent the "<" to have a character near it that would trigger the page to stop posting, then I'm okay with that.